# PowerShell: Offline Install of PKI module (Microsoft Version)

Tags: windows, powershell, pki, import-module

I'm trying to get Microsoft's PKI module imported to powershell on some offline 2008 servers, **yes, 2008 :(**,  (don't ask)

I copied the module, PKI, from the source machine's modules directory to the target machine.  Confirmed that the target directory for PKI is in $env:PSModulePath
Executed Import-Module on the target machine and:

*import-module : The module to process 'Microsoft.CertificateServices.PKIClient.Cmdlets', listed in field 'NestsedModules' of module manifest 'C:\windows\sysstem32\Windows\Powershell\v1.0\Modules\pki\pki.psd1' was not processed because no valid module was found in any module directory.*

Source Machine is 2016, PSVersion 5.1.14393.5127

Target Machine is 2008R2, PSVersion 5.1.14409.1005

Thanks in advance if anyone knows why this isn't working.

Comment: If you know where you got it from you should be able to use `Save-Module` to save it to a folder, and then copy that folder over to your offline machines. I would recommend putting it at C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules though, not at C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\1.0\Modules

Comment: Oh, you're trying to use the built in PKI module from one OS to another machine with a different OS? That seems like something prone to errors. I thought you were downloading one from the internet. Try downloading Crypt32's PSPKI and see that that'll do what you need.

Comment: As I look into this more, I'm discovering that more than just 2008 servers are having issues.  The common thread appears to be that the failing servers have Powershell 7 installed as well as Powershell v5.1  Maybe unrelated, but curious.  
I may end up having to re-write my code to use PSPKI.  Unfortunate though since the PKI module does what I need on all but a few outliers.